# Change selected link’s colour

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have some links to posts. When I click on a link, I want its color to change, just like 
the Stack Overflow menu. A selected menu is red in its open state.

This is my script right now:

```
<script>
$(".widget_listcategorypostswidget > ul > li").click(function() {
    $('.selected_1').removeClass('selected_1'); 
    $(this).addClass('selected_1');
});
</script>
```

It’s working well. However, by clicking when a new page is open, my link color returns to the default. You can see it happen at http://www.imagineideas.com.sg/pic-test-post/, below the service logo. Some post links are displayed. Now when you click a link, it will change color, but after refreshing the page, the link color is again changed.

How can I fix that?

Comment: Dunno, this works fine for me

Comment: Was the contact link done differently? It doesn't seem to share the problem

Comment: 1. Use the :active selector instead of changing colors with a "JS canon" :D

2. Add a color to your .current > a selector, its the only "state" keeping class you have - adding a class with JS will not be remembered when the browser resets.
.current > a {
   color: orange; 
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a tags, and format `a:visited` with CSS. The browser keeps track what pages have been open and formats links to those pages using this selector.

[More info](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_visited.asp)